# ASP.Net GridView JavaScript popup modal window - set transparency?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have just applied an 'onclick' event on each row of an asp gridview. The resulting popup window is working nicely.
I would like to set a transparency level on the body of the popup window to give a translucent effect. 
How can this be accomplished? Thanks.
(btw, the preferred browser is IE)

Comment: If possible, please edit your question to include your source code. That way, the community can give you the best answer to suit your needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your element to be transparent, then :

```
background-color : transparent;
```

But if you want it to be in colors, you can use:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

The problem with opacity is that it will also affect the contents.